# R bookdown: different output depending on operating system

Tags: r, pandoc, bookdown

I render the exact same R `bookdown` source, but get slightly different results depending on the operating system. This only regards the wrapping of the output width of code chunks when rendering with pandoc to HTML.

If the output is rather large like this
[image]

on Windows 10 it adds a horizontal scroll bar, when looking at it on smaller screens.
[image]

Running the same code on Ubuntu 20.04 gives me a different result
[image]

I checked the output message of `bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", "bookdown::gitbook")` and it's the exact same for both operating systems. The pandoc version is the same, too (2.11.4).

Any idea is highly appreaciated.

Comment: What does `option('width')`  say on both systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inspect `options("width")` was the right hint from `@thothal`. I explicitly set the `tibble.width` but not the `width` globally.

The lines will break without a horizontal scroll bar, if `tibble.width > width`. After updating my packages and RStudio I saw the same behavior on both operating systems. Not quiet sure though, what caused the difference in the first place. Maybe something changed for the `tibble.width` option internally. Or the default `width` depends on the OS or screen width of the device where it's run (unlikely).

To summarise: The `tibble.width` has to be equal or smaller than the global `width` to avoid that ugly line break. It's best to set both explicitly.